# GridView looses track of items in a NotIndexed location and many do not get displayed anymore

Tags: gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml, storagefile

I am using for a UWP app the `FileInformationFactory` to retrieve a Virtualized vector of files object which are cast to a `FileInformation` and displayed in a `GridView`.

I want to query a folder on a SD card plugged onto my laptop and compare the virtualization of the `GridView` when this folder is in a `FullyIndexed` location, such as my Desktop.

This SD card has a folder containing 15,000 text files of zero bytes. Each file is named `x.txt` where x runs from 1-15000 (this can be generated in a folder of your choice by clicking the Add button in the code below; it takes a minute or so on my machine, but remember to do it only once!).

The result is displayed in a `GridView` where I display the name of each file.

In a `FullyIndexed` location I can scroll up and down the `GridView` very fast, even using the vertical scrollbar very quickly and erratically and the `GridView` will always manage to show up the name of each file, albeit some delays of a few seconds.

In a `NotIndexed` location such an SD card or an external Hard Drive, the GridView displays the items as I scroll slowly but very quickly it looses track of the items as I scroll up and down too quickly, e.g. when using the vertical scroll bar with my trackpad. Waiting does not help. The app still responds but nothing gets displayed. Even when scrolling up to the top, only the first element name is shown and the only choice is to re-display the whole and scroll smoothly.

How can I solve this issue in a `NotIndexed` location? I do not want to retrieve the files one by one into memory as this takes up too much time and for real photos that will eat the user's RAM too quickly. Hence the use of the `GetVirtualizedFilesVector`.

I thought that would be a Virtualization of the GridView but it seems not the case, and furthermore the app works well with real 17k photos but only on a `FullyIndexed` location.
Thank you

```
<Page
x:Class="Virtualization.Scenario4"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ba="using:Windows.Storage.BulkAccess"
xmlns:local="using:Virtualization"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                BorderThickness="0,0,2,2">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="FolderPickerButton" Icon="Folder"
                      LabelPosition="Collapsed" Label="Select Folder"
                      Click="FolderPickerButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="ViewAll"
                      LabelPosition="Collapsed"
                      Click="ViewAllAppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add"
                      LabelPosition="Collapsed"
                      Click="AddFilesAppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarSeparator/>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemCollectionView, Mode=OneWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ba:FileInformation">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Information, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class Scenario4 : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    public Scenario4()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ICollectionView _fileCollectionView;
    private StorageFolder _folder;
    private IStorageQueryResultBase _query;
    private FileInformationFactory _fileInformationFactory;
    private object _vector;

    public CollectionViewSource CollectionViewSource { get; set; } = new CollectionViewSource();
    public ICollectionView ItemCollectionView
    {
        get { return _fileCollectionView; }
        set
        {
            if (_fileCollectionView != value)
            {
                _fileCollectionView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemCollectionView));
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Information { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private async void FolderPickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _pickedFolder = await PickFolderAsync();
        if (_pickedFolder == null)
        {
            Information.Add("Choose a folder");
            return;
        }
        Information.Add("Generate 15k files with the Add button if not done already, otherwise click the ViewAll button");
        _folder = _pickedFolder;
    }

    private async void Query_ContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            Information.Add($"Contents Changed {sender.Folder.Name} {args}");
        });
    }

    private void View_VectorChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs @event)
    {
        if (@event.CollectionChange == CollectionChange.Reset)
        {
            Information.Add($"Vector Changed {@event.CollectionChange} ItemCount: {sender.Count} Index: {@event.Index}");
        }
    }


    private static async Task<StorageFolder> PickFolderAsync()
    {
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        };

        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var _pickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        return _pickedFolder;
    }

    private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem is FileInformation fileInformation)
        {
            Information.Add(fileInformation.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem == null)
            {
                Information.Add("Null");
            }
            else
            {
                Information.Add(e.ClickedItem.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private async void AddFilesAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15000; i++)
        {
            await _folder.CreateFileAsync(i + ".txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            if (i % 250 == 0)
            {
                Information.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private async void ViewAllAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_folder == null)
        {
            Information.Add("Choose folder first");
            return;
        }
        var state = await _folder.GetIndexedStateAsync();

        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions { FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep, IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable };


        Information.Add($"{_folder.Name} is {state} {queryOptions.IndexerOption}");

        _query = _folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        var st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var numOfFiles = (await _query.GetItemCountAsync());
        st.Stop();

        Information.Add($"{state} {queryOptions.IndexerOption}. Found {numOfFiles} in {st.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0}");
        if (numOfFiles==0)
        {
            Information.Add("Generate files by clicking the Add button");
            return;
        }
        _fileInformationFactory = new FileInformationFactory(_query, ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, Constants.Thumbnail_Size,
           ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale, delayLoad: false);

        _vector = _fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();
        CollectionViewSource.Source = _vector;

        ItemCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.View;
        _query.ContentsChanged += Query_ContentsChanged;
        CollectionViewSource.View.VectorChanged += View_VectorChanged;
    }
}
```

For `Constants.Thumbnail_Size`, set it to e.g. 100.

**Addendum**

The problem is independent of an external hard drive. I created a partition on a modern Thinkpad X1 Yoga 3rd Gen which is not indexed. The issue is reproduced.

Comment: I suspect the behavior is related to the poor performance when querying file without index. I'll try to confirm this.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, note that the SD card is a modern one, and the external hard drive I tried it on, too. The files are actually loaded pretty quickly but it is the scrolling which kills it all. That is why I chose 0 bytes files, to make sure there is minimal overhead in perf.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, this cannot be only a perf of the external drive because File Explorer   works very well in displaying 15k files. I understand that File Explorer is not UWP based, but one cannot blame only the drive.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I required Windows 10 to index the USB key and it works very well. However, this is not a solution for the user since I do not see how I am going to require W10 to index this location form a UWP app.

Comment: Could you please try to use the process monitor tool to check the file system activity from your app when you are querying files from the SD card? When you scroll the scroll bar very quickly and you get the behavior in the gridview, is the system still querying files at that time. If it is, it means the reason is the poor performance when querying file without index.

Comment: The app stops querying when the behavior occurs, the app looks almost idle in the debugger as well as the taskbar monitor. Also notice, as I updated my question, that this issue occurs even on a partition of my hard drive, which is not indexed. And this is an SSD. Did you try it out?

Comment: After discussing, the team thinks the non-indexed place is the reason for this. Currently, my suggestion is to use win32 API to query the files from non-indexed places for better performance that could avoid this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific on the win32 api or function call(s) that could be used for this purpose?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm not very familiar with win32 API. So I can't tell which API is better in such a scenario.

Comment: If you have the `broadFilesystemAccess` capability, you can look into [`FindFirstFileExFromAppW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexw) and [`FindNextFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew). Note the first link goes to the non-`FromApp` API but the signature is the same. `#include fileapifromapp.h` for C++ and P/Invoke from `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll` for .NET. But then you'll have to wrap up so you can call from XAML bindings.

Comment: Or maybe if you solve [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59030434/4184842) you won't need to worry about this any more.