# How to require Windows 10 to index a USB key from a UWP app?

Tags: windows, uwp

In Windows 10 it is possible to require the OS to index a specific location such as the D drive when a USB Key is inserted.

Is it possible to this in UWP ,and how?

The idea is to request permission from the user with a `FolderPicker`, and if granted, instruct the OS to index the location of the picked location.
Thank you!

Comment: Does [`StorageLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagelibrary.requestaddfolderasync) work for you? Not sure if Windows considers a USB key a "suitable location" (it might depend on the hardware / driver -- e.g. is it considered "removable" or not). Although that begs the question of "which library would you add the folder to?" Which leads to the real question of "what is the ultimate purpose of having the folder indexed?"

Comment: @peter, yes I am adding the AddFolderAsync, which makes it indexed by default. I did not mention it but that was the only way I found to have it indexed. The problem is that I don't need the library and didn't want to prompt the user to add a folder to a library for only getting the indexing done! But that is what I am doing now, and I prompt the user in the settings telling him he can now remove the oflder from the library, because indexing remains as a left over (which is good). Feel free to add this as an answer I will be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: As for your request, oh yes I need the indexing because I am using the FileInformation factory and after several tests it does not work properly on non-indexed locations. No doubt it should be indexed until the API is improved. BTW the FileInformationfactory is a real gem,

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, the method you gave does not work with subfolders. Which kills the purpose. I need the indexing to make the FileInformationFactory work flawlessly. Any alternative? The app is for photos and videos, but I had to make a choice and went for the picture library.

Comment: reminder about the aforementioned limitation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978986/gridview-looses-track-of-items-in-a-notindexed-location-and-many-do-not-get-disp

Comment: OK sorry, my mistake. During testing I was launching the indexing options from Windows 10 to allow testing again non-indexed locations, but this had the effect of having windows excluding those folders, hence my complaint about subfolders. Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StorageLibrary.RequestAddFolderAsync
```

here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagelibrary.requestaddfolderasync

This adds the folder to the library, which gets indexed, as desired. This seems to be the only possible solution as of now.

Credits to  Peter Torr-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

UWP does not currently provide APIs for indexing drive files.

File indexing is usually established when a user begins to access a file. As you have done, you can use `FolderPicker` to let the user pick the file and the system will create an index for it, but the UWP app cannot interfere with this process

Best regards.

Comment: I can access the USB Key without the removableStorage capability. I can access it and open a folder there and list the files without issue. My question is about requiring W10 to index it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean. But UWP does not provide an API for indexing files in the drive. This process should be implicit and index only when the user needs it.